# Call private internal function from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Is it possible for me to call from a contract B, that has an instance of A, a private or internal function of contract A?

Comment: no, it's not possible.

Comment: As much as this is a beginner question and can be found in the Solidity docs, I feel like this question gets asked by roughly every junior Solidity dev at some point to see if there's a way to hack around it, and they almost always land here. I consider this question here to be a public service, thanks for asking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot call a private or internal function in another contract.

> - `private`: only visible in the current contract
> - `internal`: only visible internally

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/cheatsheet.html#function-visibility-specifiers

Private functions can only be called from the same contract, whereas internal functions can be called from the same contract, as well as contracts inheriting from that contract. They are usually private or internal for a reason. If it's your own contract, you can create a public function in contract A, that you can call from B.

Comment: "`internal`: only visible internally" won't mean anything to anyone who doesn't already know what `internal` is and what exactly it is used for.

Comment: You're right. I added a brief explanation to explain the difference.

Comment: You could simply just use the same pattern you've used for the first bullet (e.g., "`internal`: visible in the current contract as well as every inheriting contract").

Comment: This is quoted from the Solidity documentation directly.